# GridView removes a row

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have my `<asp:GridView ID="gridView" runat="server">`  I bind it like this :

```
        myConnection.Open();
        SqlCommand myCommand = myConnection.CreateCommand();
        myCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        myCommand.CommandText = "sp_SelectWeek";

        myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Division", Convert.ToInt32(e.PostBackValue));
        SqlDataReader myReader = myCommand.ExecuteReader();
        myReader.Read();

        gridView.DataSource = myReader;
        gridView.DataBind();

        myReader.Close();
        myConnection.Close();`
```

but when I run it It takes off one rowfrom the query. I'm sure of this because I tried it with a table and all the rows where there.  I build a chart from the same query and you clearly see that I have one row missing :

[image]

What am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're calling

```
myReader.Read();
```

before you pass the reader as a data source. So you moved the record pointer effectively. Thereby losing your one row. Just don't call Read and you should be good.

Comment: I just don't call it ? 
Or I call it after ?

Comment: You don't call it at all. When you call databind, the databind method does all the reads for you. You only call Read to get the next row in the reader.

Comment: I tried it and it works perfecly! 10 internets to you sir! :-)